# Error cleaning up agent threads using okhttp3 in HCL Domino agent

Tags: java, xpages, okhttp, hcl-domino

I am using okhttp3 in an Notes Agent and every time it runs I get the message "Error cleaning up agent threads" in the console.

I get the same message if I run the agent in Notes 14 client or on the Domino server 12.02.FP2. the jar files are in the jar design object

[image]

```
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;
public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase {

    OkHttpClient client;
    public void NotesMain() {

        try {
            Session session = getSession();
            AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();
    
            client = new OkHttpClient();
            Response response = null;
            Request request = new Request.Builder().url("https://www.cnn.com").build();

            try {
                response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (response != null) {
                    response.close();
                }
            }
    
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    
    }

}
```

how can I resolve this error?

Here is an updated try based on comments:

```
try {
            Session session = getSession();
            AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();
            Response response = null;
            try {
    
                client = new OkHttpClient();
                Request request = new Request.Builder().url("https://www.cnn.com").build();
                response = client.newCall(request).execute();

                System.out.println("isTerminated: " + client.dispatcher().executorService().isTerminated());
                System.out.println("isShutDown: " + client.dispatcher().executorService().isShutdown());
                System.out.println("Calling ShutDownNow");
                client.dispatcher().executorService().shutdownNow();
                System.out.println("isTerminated: " + client.dispatcher().executorService().isTerminated());
                System.out.println("isShutDown: " + client.dispatcher().executorService().isShutdown());
                
                dumptg(null);
                
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (response != null) {
                    response.close();
                }
            }
    
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


Result:

 isTerminated: false
    isShutDown: false
    Calling ShutDownNow
    isTerminated: true
    isShutDown: true
    ThreadGroup UTG: JavaAgent, objid = -728930514
      subgroups  = 0
      total threads = 6
    
    Thread Name, ThreadID, ThreadGroup
    OkHttp TaskRunner, 1876182108, UTG: JavaAgent
    OkHttp TaskRunner, -536891291, UTG: JavaAgent
    Okio Watchdog, 511103762, UTG: JavaAgent
    OkHttp TaskRunner, -485203566, UTG: JavaAgent
    OkHttp www.cnn.com, -1274389829, UTG: JavaAgent
    AgentThread: JavaAgent, 201675379, UTG: JavaAgent
    Error cleaning up agent threads
```

Comment: We have removed any use of threads in our code in agents because threads is kept alive and eventually crashes the server. That is my conclusion, and it was never the case in version 9 but any version after that.

Comment: do you mean you do not use any external jars that use seperate threads?

Answer (score 2):

Edit: it looks like OkHttp3 [has the shutdown function](https://square.github.io/okhttp/5.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-ok-http-client/index.html) that can be used directly.
After your code is done, call
`client.dispatcher().executorService().shutdown();` in  a finally block. You may experiment with `shutdownNow()` instead of `shutdown()` and may need to add `awaitTermination()`.

You don't need the below code for OkHttp, but I'm leaving if here as a generic method.

--

IME if new threads are created in code running in an agent, they must be cleaned up before agend ends or you get that exact error message. Ignoring this message long enough will bring the server down.

If you use some third party thing that creates new threads, but doesn't clean them up, you could investigate to find out if you can provide your own threads and do the cleanup yourself.

I don't know okhttp3 or if there is a way with okhttp3, but something like this has worked fine for years with a particular third party library, in agents running on Domino v9 to v12:

```
ExecutorService executorService = null;
try {
  Thing thing = Thing.getInstance();
  if (thing.hasThingsToDo()) {
    executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
    thing.setThreadExecutor(executorService);
    thing.doThings();
  }
} finally {
  if (executorService != null) {
    executorService.shutdownNow();
    executorService.awaitTermination(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }
}
```

PS. It's more complicated in XPages, but can be done there too.

Comment: Thanks. How do I use that code? At the end of my code?

Comment: Your code goes where the hypothetical "thing" is doing it's task.  The point is to feed the library that wants to spawn threads, with a thread executor that you can control.
But like I said, you need to investigate if the okhttp3 has any exposed method that allos you to do this.

Comment: Check the edits to my answer, seems like OkHttp allows you to shut it down directly so you don't need to provide own executor in this case.

Comment: I updated my post with results, looks like the OKHttp is terminated and shutdowned.

Comment: Better to place the shutdownNow() in the finally block (where the response.close() is), so it will get called even if there are exceptions thrown somewhere in the main code.

Comment: true, but the message is still present

Comment: Check the documentation I linked, part titled "Shutdown Isn't Necessary". It may be necessary to call additional functions to clear connection pool and note it says "the connection pool's daemon thread may not exit immediately". You may need to wait until only the agent thread remains.